# How do you get the "Rotisserie Chicken" achievement in Grow Home?

Tags: grow-home

How do you "Float a warble creature in an anti-gravity flower"?

I've tried just putting the warble into the flower.  That shoots the warble into the air, but it falls back down instead of floating and the achievement is not unlocked so I assume there is more to it than that.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anti-gravity flower is in a cave on the island with the 4th teleporter.  There is a cave entrance in the cliff below the teleporter.

The anti-gravity flower is grey and may have one of the pink flower chains floating in it.  The cave contains a warble so you don't need to bring one from somewhere else.  Once you have found the cave all you need to do is drag the warble into the flower so he floats for a bit without falling out immediately.

[This video](https://youtu.be/1Snf-zT24JI) from [ardaozkal's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/209127/70797) shows the entire process.

My problem was that I mistakenly thought that the bubbling flowers were anti-gravity flowers.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I didn't understand what you are doing wrong, so can you please see [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Snf-zT24JI) and compare the things you are doing? I believe that the video will be an answer for you.

Comment: Do you think you could explain?

Comment: @aytimothy I didn't understand what he is doing wrong, so I offer him to watch this video. BTW sent friend request on steam.

Comment: My mistake was that I thought the bubbling flowers were the anti-gravity flowers

Comment: @numaroth please select this as the answer if I helped you.

Comment: @numaroth I will. Soon.